# Full screen not working when npx testcafe 'chrome --start-fullscreen' is defined in package.json file - testcafe

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, ui-testing

I am learning testcafe and I am a newbie here.

According to testcafe docs the command
 `npx testcafe 'chrome --start-fullscreen'` 
should open full screen and run tests, which is doing the job perfectly. But when I defined the same command under scripts tag in package.json file, it's not opening the full screen

```
  "scripts": {
    "testsOnChrome": "npx testcafe 'chrome --start-fullscreen'"

  }
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert the command `chrome --start-fullscreen` in double quotes `"` instead of single quote `'`

use this

```
"testsOnChrome": "npx testcafe \"chrome --start-fullscreen\""
```